# spring controller exception/error page rendering

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have the following controller code. This will show a list of banks in the front end in a table with in a jquery tabbed pane. /bankList.do is called when the user clicks on of the tab. banksList.jsp will be rendered with in the tab on success.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/banksList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView banksList() throws Exception {
   BankList banksList = bankService.list();
   return new ModelAndView("banksList", "banksList", banksList.getBanks());
}
```

I dont know how to handle the error/exceptions that are thrown in the bankend.
When there is exception in the bank end, i want to show the user with the following text "Error while communicating to backend, please try again later." without displaying the table in the tabbed pane. How do i make changes in the above controller in order to implement the error functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538031/spring-mvc-best-practice-handling-unrecoverable-exceptions-in-controller

Answer (score 2):

You can define `@Exceptionhandler`-annotated methods to handle your service-layer exceptions. See [16.11 Handling exceptions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) and especially [16.11.2 @ExceptionHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way, add something like this to your controller class ...

```
@ExceptionHandler({SomeException.class, SomeOtherException.class})
public String doException(final Exception e, final HttpSession session) {
    LOGGER.error("something failed", e);
    session.setAttribute(UPLOAD_STATUS, false);
    session.setAttribute(ERROR_MESSAGE, e.getMessage());
    return "redirect:" + VIEW_NAME;
}
```

Comment: <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
  <property name="exceptionMappings">
   <map>
    <entry key="com.myapp.simulator.service.impl.ServiceConnectionException" value="connectionError"/>
   </map>
  </property> 
  <property name="defaultErrorView" value="generalErrorPage" />
 </bean> configured in the context.xml and added connectionError.jsp page to my webapp

Comment: There is always more than one way to do things in Spring MVC.